# Is the Axiom of Choice needed here?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the following two statements:

(1) Let $S$ and $T$ be nonempty sets, and let $\mathcal{T}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(T)$. Then:
$$S\cup\left(\bigcap_{X\in \mathcal{T}}X\right) = \bigcap_{X\in\mathcal{T}}(S\cup X).$$
(2) Let $\{T_j\}_{j\in J}$ be an indexed family of subsets of the nonempty set $T$, and let $S$ be a nonempty set. Then:
$$S\cup\left(\bigcap_{j\in J}T_j\right) = \bigcap_{j\in J}(S\cup T_j).$$
Would the second be a corollary to the first, assuming the axiom of choice? My reasoning is, in the second statement we essentially have $\mathcal{T} = \{T_j\ |\ j\in J\}$, the only thing left to do is to turn $\mathcal{T}$ into an indexed family, which amounts to assigning elements of $\mathcal{T}$ to elements of $J$ (for a suitable $J$). Is this correct?

Comment: You can turn any family into an indexed family: just index it by itself. For $T\in\mathscr{T}$ let $S_T=T$; then $\{S_T:T\in\mathscr{T}\}$ is an indexing of $\mathscr{T}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That clears it up, thanks.

Comment: My pleasure! $\,$

Answer (score 1):

The axiom of choice is not needed at all for either one.

$$x\in S\cup\left(\bigcap_{j\in J}T_j\right)\iff x\in S\lor\forall j\in J: x\in T_j\iff\forall j\in J: x\in S\lor x\in T_j\\\iff x\in\bigcap_{j\in J}(S\cup T_j)$$

And of course this applies to the first one, since $\mathcal T$ is a family of sets, indexed by itself.

(Note however that if $\mathcal T$, or $J$, is empty, the result is not a set.)

Comment: I appreciate the reply, but I was asking if I needed the axiom of choice in order to have the first statement imply the second. I understand why they are true in general.

Comment: The answer shows that the second statement is *just true* without even appealing to the axiom of choice. Since everything implies a true proposition, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the axiom of choice since you can write

$$\bigcap_{j \in J} \dots = \bigcap_{T \in \{ T_j : j \in J\}} \dots$$